# How to show closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are $\sigma$-compact?

Tags: general-topology

How to see that every uncountable closed subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of countably many compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For each $n\ge 1$, let $C_n=[-n,n]\cap A$. Then $C_n$ is closed since it an intersection of two closed sets. It is clearly bounded. So it is compact. But $A=\bigcup_n C_n$, proving the claim. (the information that $A$ is uncountable is redundant.)