# $R^{n}$ is σ-compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

$R^{n}$ is σ-compact? How can I view this? Thanks
A topological space is said to be σ-compact if it is the union of countably many compact subspaces.

Comment: I don't know how you can view it. I think a proof is the best. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342604/how-to-show-closed-subsets-of-mathbbr-are-sigma-compact).

Comment: Choose your favorite compact neighborhood $K$ of the origin (closed unit ball, e.g.) and consider $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} nK$.

Answer (score 0):

By Tychonoff Theorem, $I^n=[0,1]^n$ is compact space.

And $\Bbb Z^n$ is surely countable, and if $p\in\Bbb Z^n$, $I\cong p+I$(translation preserves compactness)

$\Bbb R^n=\bigcup_{p\in\Bbb Z^n}{p+I^n}$, so $\Bbb R^n$ is $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Surely there are more elementary ways to prove thst $I^n$ is compact ...

Comment: Thanks @MaoWao, I realized after reading your comment. Heine-Borel was enough.